# Can single thread in php handle simultaneous client connections using mpm prefork module?

Tags: php, apache, websocket, real-time

I was studying php vs nodejs i.e. blocking vs non-blocking architecture and stucked at one point. If considering apache mpm prefork module so php will spawn a new thread to serve each request. On the other side there are libs such as Rachet, Elephant.io, phpsocket.io, phpDeamon etc using which you can create a node.js like server and easily build a chat app using it.

But if each request lands on a different process (in case of prefork) or different thread (in case of worker or event) than how are these libs actually working? Are they using IPC for communication b/w process or threads? Or what is actually going on behind?

What is actually going behind is driving me crazy. Need some explanations on this.

Answer (score 0):

phpsocket.io doesn't use processes or light-weight processes (threads). It's an [event based server](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php).

The server executes as a single thread and waits for new connections / closed connections / activity on the current set of open connections. When one of these occurs, it responds appropriately and goes back to wait for the next event.

Comment: Client 1 connects to server and the server goes in event loop. Now client 2 connects so will it connect to the same thread or apache will spawn a new process/thread for it (considering using prefork mpm module in apache)?

Comment: no, No, NO. You DO NOT RUN multi-client code in an Apache request handler. Either run a server written in PHP outside of Apache, or handle one client at a time inside Apache. If you RTFM you'll see that most of the relevant functionality for a server is not available in anything other than the CLI SAPI.